# Allocation memory dynamically and dereferencing

Tags: c++

I've declared a pointer to an int called height.

I've assigned memory for this pointer to an int by using new int.

I then set height to an integer I pass into the constructor.

However, when I call the function infoheight(), I don't get 185 for the height based on the integer I passed in?

Anyone know why?

```
 class Person{
        public:
            Person(int a, string myname);
            int* height;
            string name;
            void infoheight();
            void infoname();

    };

    Person::Person(int a, string myname){
        height = new int;
        height = &a;
        name = myname;
    }

    void Person::infoheight(){
        cout << "Height: " << *(height) << endl;
    }

    void Person::infoname(){
        cout << "Name: " << this->name << endl;
    }


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        Person Michael(185, "Michael");
        Michael.infoname();
        Michael.infoheight();


        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Just do height=a; (make height a regular integer) Why are you try memory allocation stuff for something as simple as a single primitive integer?

Comment: Just trying to learn

Comment: Then learn the good way : learn to use *smart pointers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two lines:

```
height = new int;
height = &a;
```

You are first manually allocating a new `int`, then assigning the address of that newly allocated `int` to `height`, and *then* you are overwriting that address by assigning the address of `a` to `height`. This is a certain memory leak, since you no longer have access to an object that you'll need to `delete` later. If your intention was to write the *value* of `a` to the `int` *pointed to* by `height`, you need to dereference `height` like so:

```
height = new int;
*height = a;
```

Or, equivalently:

```
height = new int(a);
```

But unless you *really* need pointer semantics, just store `height` by value, not by pointer. This will make your code far simpler and less error-prone.

```
class Person{
    public:
        Person(int a, string myname);
        int height; // make this an int, not int*
        string name;
        ...
};

Person::Person(int a, string myname)
    : height(a), name(myname) { // this is a member initialization list

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new int` returns a pointer.

and then you immediately replace that pointer with `&a`. Don't do that.

You probably wanted to do `*height = a`

Although this sort of messing around with pointers and dynamic allocation is fine for experimenting and learning, you'd never do it like that in real life. C++ isn't Java, you don't need to call new on everything.

You may want to do this in a "Modern C++" style.

- Use smart pointers and never use `new` or delete at all, ever.
  Note that just using that unique_ptr in the class saves you from problems with copying it (it disables copying) and destroys it properly when `Person` is destroyed, all without needing to write a deleted copy constructor or an explicit destructor.
- Use constructor initialization instead of the constructor function block to set your class member values.
  This is just good practice because in advanced C++ it becomes required in order to initialize inherited classes, references and const values.
- Don't use capital letters for variable names. Unless they are global. You should not have global variables, as a general rule.
- Don't build member functions that just set or return a class member.
  Operations on an object should mean something. With this Person instead of `set_name` it might have `rename`. Instead of `set_height` it could have `grow`.
  And in your case instead of `infoname` something like `output` or `dump` or the C++ generally understood `operator<<` output stream writer.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Person {
   public:
    Person(int h, std::string n) : height(std::make_unique<int>(h)), name(n) {}

   private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> height;
    std::string name;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p) {
        return os << "{name: " << p.name << ", height: " << *p.height << "}";
    }
};

int main() {
    Person michael(185, "Michael");
    std::cout << michael << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does height = new int(a) do? This give me the right answer

Comment: It allocates a new integer, sets its initial value to `a`, and sets `height` to point to it.